# Do Spartan Ops Missions Go Away?

Tags: halo-4

I purchased and played Halo 4 when it was released last winter. I only played one **Spartan Ops** mission. I had only downloaded the first episode at that point (it was the only one out at the time), so I'm not caught up on the current missions.

Can I still download and play all the older missions, even this long after original release?

Comment: The first 5 Episodes are on-disc content, they just unlocked them one week at a time.  You'll have access to all 5 of these Episodes without doing anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all the Spartan Ops missions are available still.  The "second season" is free DLC, so you might have another download if you want to play past the 5th Episode.

All the ops are available in single player, splitscreen, and party play, but the chapters featured in online matchmaking rotate.  The experience gain from the online matchmaking is far greater, and you can play with random people on the internet, but otherwise they are identical.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really interested with the Spartan Ops Matchmaking - more interested in the storyline than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Like most Shooters, special missions are available throughout their release and here after. There are no 'expiry dates' on these Op missions so you are able to play these if and when you desire.